# Crear Fila de tabla automaticamente en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una lista de productos quiero que cuando se pase de 5 productos estos se creen en una nueva fila de la tabla con mas productos.
[estos son los productos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD62F.png)
Tenía pensado utilizar un for each pero no se bien como utilizarlo.
Este es el codigo que me crea la tabla
[Codigo Tabla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG56Y.png)

```
enter code here
```

echo "";
echo "";

```
                    echo "<tr>";
                        //Meter un bucle para cuando llegue a 5 repeticiones, introduzca <tr>
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                echo "<td>";
                                    echo "<form action='info_producto.php' method='get'>";
                                        echo "<a href='info_producto.php?producto=".$row['ID_PRODUCTO']."&mesa=".$id_mesa."'>";
                                        echo "<input hidden='true' id='id_mesa' name='id_mesa' value='".$id_mesa."'>";
                                            echo "<center><img class='producto' src='../img_productos/". $row['ID_PRODUCTO'] . ".jpg'></center>";
                                                echo "<br>";
                                                   
                                        echo "<center>". $row[NOMBRE]. "</center>";
                                    echo "</a>".  "";
                                    echo "</form>";
                                echo "</td>";
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo "No hay Productos";
                            
                        }
                            echo "</tr>";
                        echo "</table>";
                    echo "</center>";
```

Comment: Lleva un contador dentro del `while` y cuando éste sea igual a 5 crea la nueva fila y reinicia el contador. Aunque veo muy raro eso de meter un formulario en los td ¿?

Comment: Te dejo abajo todo el codigo,  a ver si así lo ves más claro

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te pongo el ejemplo con ese trozo de codigo, lo que tienes que hacer es que al llegar a 5, calcular que el resto de la división entre 5 del número sea igual a 0, de este modo te aseguras que cada 5 veces, te haga el salto de linea, esto se hace con poniendo un contador y haciendo que vaya sumando en cada vuelta.

```
echo "<tr>";
//Meter un bucle para cuando llegue a 5 repeticiones, introduzca <tr>
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $contador = 0;
    // while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) as $row) {

        echo "<td>";
            echo "<form action='info_producto.php' method='get'>";
                echo "<a href='info_producto.php?producto=".$row['ID_PRODUCTO']."&mesa=".$id_mesa."'>";
                echo "<input hidden='true' id='id_mesa' name='id_mesa' value='".$id_mesa."'>";
                    echo "<center><img class='producto' src='../img_productos/". $row['ID_PRODUCTO'] . ".jpg'></center>";
                        echo "<br>";
                           
                echo "<center>". $row['NOMBRE']. "</center>";
            echo "</a>".  "";
            echo "</form>";
        echo "</td>";
        
        $contador++;
        if ($contador % 5 == 0) {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
    }
    // }
}else{
    echo "No hay Productos";
    
}
echo "</tr>";
```